# A question on C style ellipses and what the printf family argument size specifications actually means

Tags: c++

As I understand it, when passing values to a function parameter that is encompassed with the C style ellipses, the values can get promoted.

1. `signed`/`unsigned` `char` and `short` get promoted to respective `signed`/`unsigned` `int`
2. `float` gets promoted to a `double`

Wikipedia's [variadic arguments page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) also qualifies that:

> `bool`, `char`, `short`, and unscoped enumerations are converted to `int` *or wider integer types* as in integer promotion

*(emphasis mine)*

I'm not exactly sure what *or wider integer types* actually means.  If `long` is greater in length than an `int` then, it is made as long as a `long` or does this just state that this is implementation defined behaviour on the compiler?

What is not stated is what happens to other larger types, such as `long long` and `long double` and possibly `long` if it is longer than an `int` on the compiler.  I'm assuming that they are passed as is, it would make sense, but there's no explicit statement on the matter.

Assuming that larger types are just passed as is, then the size specifications would make sense, for the larger types.  However, what about the smaller types?  Wikipedia's [length field page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Length_field) states:

> hh - For integer types, causes printf to expect an `int`-sized integer argument which was promoted from a `char`.
>
> h - For integer types, causes printf to expect an `int`-sized integer argument which was promoted from a `short`.

I think that *integer types* should be replaced with *integral types* TBH, but ignoring that, if the compiler has already done any applicable promotions and function has already lost track of the types, then the expected *`int`-side integer argument which was promoted from XXX*, actually means *the possibly promoted `int`-side integer argument*, regardless what it was promoted from, and that it will truncate it to the size specified.

Is that what is meant?

Answer (score 0):

Although embarrassingly concrete, in every useful execution model their is a minimum sized item that can be pushed on the stack.  In every important case, it corresponds to the native word size of the machine:  32bit CPU : 32bit stack element; 64bit CPU : 64bit stack element.

A variadic C functions arguments are composed of word sized and aligned objects:

1. Smaller items are expanded to wordsize.
2. Larger items are aligned to wordsize.

So, if I called a variadic function with arguments:

```
 (short a, char b, long c, struct { int a; long b; } d)
```

on a machine where the word size was the same as sizeof(int)
it would be passed as:

```
  (int a, int b, struct { int lo,hi; } c, union { struct { int a, long b }; int x[3] } d)
```

and a machine where word size was the same as long:

```
  (long a, long b, long c, union { struct { int a; long b; }; long x[2]; } d)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how this answers my question.  It is a tangential answer?